# How to integrate the android/ios library provided by others into kmm?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I want to develop a dating app through kmm. I use a third-party sdk. The third party only provides the sdk for the android/ios platform. The SDK provides many APIs. The apis on the android/ios platform are basically Keeping consistent, how to integrate it in kmm?

Or how to make the sdk of the android/ios platform into a general module and introduce it into kmm for use

android sdk:
https://doc-zh.zego.im/article/5564

mac sdk:
https://doc-zh.zego.im/article/3124

I read the official documentation, but I don't understand it very well.

Comment: Every situation is different. I gave a talk about this last year. The page has the wrong title, but the video is correct: https://www.droidcon.com/2022/06/28/sdk-design-and-publishing-for-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile/

Comment: Thank you for your question and answer. After watching the video, I don’t know how to start. Is there any specific related documentation tutorials or operation steps? Since these SDKs are provided by others, they may be encrypted or confused, so there is no way to update the SDK. For transformation, only one layer can be made on top of sdk to facilitate calling in kmm

Comment: If you can't modify the SDK, you can't really use it on platforms other than Android/iOS. But if the APIs are public, you could potentially write your own extension for whichever platform you want. Then write a wrapper (expect class) over the SDK and your custom implementation to share the code across platforms.